# Add Entire Files Text as Map Key in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm looking for a way to load an entire file text into my map.  Not a single line at a time like `TextInputFormat` does.
So that when I do `value.toString` in my map it gives me the entire input to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put every line into a `StringBuilder` until you've reached the end of file. Or you override your own RecordReader that provides this functionality. But I would not recommend this.

Comment: Which one would you not recommend? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I would path name of the file to the mapper, and then will be free to load is entirely or do some kind of streaming processing.